# Why is PHP not allowing comparison?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I'm using PHP to read if an entry in my table on the database is set to "yes" or "no" and auto check the radio button that corresponds:

```
<?php include 'file.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$runquery = odbc_exec($connect,$query);
$status= odbc_result($runquery,"status");
odbc_close($file);
?>
<form>
<div class="formContainer">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Campus Alert<span class="tooltip">Turn campus alert on and off.</span></legend>
        <?php echo $status; ?>
        Yes <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus" value="yes" <?php if($status== "yes") echo "checked";?>>
        No <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus" value="no" <?php if($status== "no") echo "checked";?>>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

the `<?php echo $status; ?>` is for debugging so I can make sure what the database says and the form's reaction is correct. It prints "yes" (no quotes). However, the if statement will not respond. Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Are you sure $status = "yes"? You should see "yes Yes" (without quotes) on the first line (before the first radiobutton)...

Comment: that is exactly what I see. That's why it's throwing me. I can see $status is "yes" with that echo so I know I'm returning the correct thing from the DB but the if statement doesn't like it.

Comment: Should we assume you can't turn the database field into a `Boolean` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing your if statements to something like

```
<?php if(strtolower(trim($status)) == "yes") echo "checked";?>
```

Comment: The fact that `trim` did the trick implies there is leading or trailing white space in the database field. It is probably worth investigating where this is coming from.

Comment: That's why you must debug with var_dump() rather than echo

Answer (score 1):

It's not very good practise to use "yes/no" for your `$status`, you're better off using an `int` or `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's really weird... the problem isn't with your PHP. First of all, You should remove the id attributes from those fields. But the real issue is that Firefox doesn't seem to want to check the second field when it has the name alertStatus. if you change the name to something else, it seems to be working. I'm not really sure why this is though.

Here's my test code:

```
<?php //include 'file.php';
//$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
//$runquery = odbc_exec($connect,$query);
//$status= odbc_result($runquery,"status");
//odbc_close($file);
$status='no';
?>
<form>
<div class="formContainer">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Campus Alert<span class="tooltip">Turn campus alert on and off.</span></legend>
        <?php echo $status; ?>
        Yes <input type="radio" name="alertStatu" value="yes" <?php if($status== "yes") echo "checked";?>>
        No <input type="radio" name="alertStatu" value="no" <?php if($status== "no") echo "checked";?>>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: if i set $status to a specific value like yes or no by doing $status = "yes" or $status = "no" it works. It only breaks when I set the value by pulling off the DB. I went into my code and change nothing other than that and it works.

Comment: This isn't to do with with the specific name of the field e.g. "alertStatus". When you refresh the page Firefox remembers the previous data from your form fields and restores the form to this state, overriding the "checked" that is in the HTML source. You need to do a full refresh (Ctrl+F5) instead. This is why renaming the field appeared to help because Firefox doesn't have a remembered value for the new name.

Comment: Oh... Well I guess I fail that one XD. Good to know though, since that didn't make any sense. Thanks for pointing that out >_<

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page source you'll see that the `check` is actually there. However, you have a duplicate ID and the browser is getting confused. Replace:

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus" ....>
No <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus" .....>
```

with

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus:yes" ....>
No <input type="radio" name="alertStatus" id="alertStatus:no" .....>
```

and it'll fix.